# jQuery find|filter issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get each div's from http://toster.ru :

```
var find = html.find('div'); //html - source code
if(!find.length) return;
find.each(function(index, el){
                //there i show each div
            });
```

I don't know why the code offset first div, i recieve first div#js-canvas, instead parent div 
[image]

And with find() i cann't to get head>title tag and because i begin to use filter() - can to get title tag also can to get parent DIV, but cann't to show all another div.

Comment: i guess it should be `$('html')` ?? should be `var find = $('html').find('div')`

Comment: Somebody add and delete answer which one solved my problem - var find = $('<div />').html(output).find(selector);

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody add and delete answer which solved my problem -

```
var find = $('<div />').html(output).find(selector);
```

thanks